# How to display all the partitions in a tree-like format (primary, extended and logical)?

Tags: command-line, filesystems

I'm trying to find something that resembles the output of `findmnt` but with volumes instead mount-points (example):

```
TARGET                       TYPE        FSTYPE  
sda 
├─sda1                       Primary     ext4
│ └─/
├─sda2                       Primary     NTFS    
├─sda3                       Primary     ext4 
│ └─/boot
└─sda4                       Extended
  ├─sda5                     Logical     ext4
  │ └─/home
  └─sda6                     Logical     ext4
    └─/var
```

The show of TYPE and FSTYPE is optional, what interest me more is the tree layout.

The output of `lsblk` is somewhat incomplete since it doesn't show the differences between Primary, Extended and Logical partitions. (I know I'm being picky here):

```
lsblk -a
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 186.3G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 106.6G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  52.8G  0 part /media/F66E431C6E42D551
├─sda3   8:3    0  1023M  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   953M  0 part /boot
├─sda6   8:6    0   487M  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda7   8:7    0    14G  0 part /
└─sda8   8:8    0  10.5G  0 part /home
```

I know that `sda4` extended partition includes `sda5`, `sda6`, `sda7`, `sda8` logical partitions; but if I was seeing someone else output I wouldn't know. If instead of `part` and `disk` it saids `pri` `log` and `ext` would be a good alternative, at least I know the relationship. But since all are `part`s... no good.

`sudo fdisk -l` output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 200.0 GB, 200049647616 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 24321 cylinders, total 390721968 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1549f232

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   223629311   111814624+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       225724416   336437306    55356445+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       223629312   225724415     1047552   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4       336439294   390721535    27141121    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       336439296   338391039      975872   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       338393088   339390463      498688   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       339392512   368687103    14647296   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       368689152   390721535    11016192   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all you want is an `lsblk` that shows you primary/logical partitions, you should be able to do this with a combination of `fdisk` and parsing. `fdisk -l` if run as root will list all partitions and will mark extended ones with `Ext'd`:

```
# fdisk -l | grep dev
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
/dev/sda1              63       80324       40131   de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2   *       81920    30801919    15360000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        30801920   194643539    81920810    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       194643601   976773119   391064759+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       194643603   198836504     2096451    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda6       342951936   960387071   308717568   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       198840320   342949887    72054784   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       960389120   976773119     8192000   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

You could then combine that with a little parsing to get the output you want:

```
$ lsblk -a | perl -lpe 'BEGIN{open(A,"sudo fdisk -l |");
                      while(<A>){next unless /Ext/; 
                                 $k{$1}++ if /^.*?(...\d)\s/; }} 
                      @a=split(/\s+/);
                      $a[0]=~s/\W+//;
                      s/$a[5]/Extended/ if defined($k{$a[0]});'
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  39.2M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  14.7G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0  78.1G  0 part /winblows
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 Extended 
├─sda5   8:5    0     2G  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0 294.4G  0 part /home
├─sda7   8:7    0  68.7G  0 part /
└─sda8   8:8    0   7.8G  0 part [SWAP]
```

I think that's the best you can do since `findmnt` won't show extended partitions since they will never be mounted. Otherwise, you could parse it in the same way.

Answer (score 12):

#### blkid

You can use the command `blkid` to show something along those lines:

```
$ blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="SYSTEM_DRV" UUID="XXXXXX" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Windows7_OS" UUID="XXXXX" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Lenovo_Recovery" UUID="XXXX" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="XXXX" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="XXXX" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_root: UUID="XXXX" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_swap: UUID="XXXX" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_home: UUID="XXXX" TYPE="ext4"
```

I've removed the UUIDs from above and replaced them with X's. The command `blkid` also can take arguments if you want different output.

For example:

```
$ blkid -o list
device                         fs_type      label         mount point                        UUID
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sda1                      ntfs         SYSTEM_DRV    (not mounted)                      XXXX
/dev/sda2                      ntfs         Windows7_OS   (not mounted)                      XXXX
```

#### lsblk

An alternative tool to `blkid` is `lsblk`. You could use the following options to list all the block devices:

```
$ lsblk -a
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                          7:0    0         0 loop 
loop1                          7:1    0         0 loop 
loop2                          7:2    0         0 loop 
loop3                          7:3    0         0 loop 
loop4                          7:4    0         0 loop 
loop5                          7:5    0         0 loop 
loop6                          7:6    0         0 loop 
loop7                          7:7    0         0 loop 
sda                            8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1                         8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                         8:2    0 465.3G  0 part 
  ├─vg_totoro-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0 431.5G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vg_totoro-lv_swap (dm-1) 253:1    0  13.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─vg_totoro-lv_home (dm-2) 253:2    0    20G  0 lvm  /home
sr0                           11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Check out it's usage, it takes additional options.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't shows me the extended volumes nor the organization.

Comment: @Braiam - I see what you're looking for, you want to see the partitions in the extended partitions too. Hmm...

Comment: @Braiam - does that help?

Comment: I looked at that early, didn't got the expected results. It shows me the partitions but I have no way to differentiate logical volumes from primary... mm... more thickening...

Comment: `blkid` is unreliable for this use-case. From `man blkid`: `Note that blkid reads information directly from devices, and for non-root users it returns cached unverified information. It is better to use lsblk --fs to get a user-friendly overview of filesystems and devices. lsblk(8) is also easy to use in scripts. blkid is mostly designed for system services and to test libblkid functionality.`

Answer (score 4):

Try 
`lsblk -sf -o MOUNTPOINT,FSTYPE,NAME`

```
[root@test01 ~]# lsblk -sf -o MOUNTPOINT,FSTYPE,NAME
MOUNTPOINT FSTYPE      NAME
                       sr0
/boot      ext4        sda1
                       └─sda
[SWAP]     swap        sdb1
                       └─sdb
/          ext4        rootvg-slashlv
           LVM2_member └─sda2
                           └─sda
/apps      ext4        appvg-applv
           LVM2_member └─sdc
/home      ext4        rootvg-homelv
           LVM2_member ├─sda2
                       │ └─sda
           LVM2_member └─sdd1
                         └─sdd
/var       ext4        rootvg-varlv
           LVM2_member └─sda2
                         └─sda 
/tmp       ext4        rootvg-tmplv
           LVM2_member └─sda2
                         └─sda 
/org       ext4        rootvg-orglv
           LVM2_member └─sda2
                         └─sda
[root@test01 ~]#
```

Comment: This looks hideous, but it does what I wanted :D

Comment: PARTTYPENAME prints "W95 FAT32" as 2 columns unfortunately, but this is a great simple option

Answer (score 3):

You can list types of partitions with `parted`:

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sda print
Model: ATA ST3320613AS (scsi)
Dysk /dev/sda: 320GB
Rozmiar sektora (logiczny/fizyczny): 512B/512B
Tablica partycji: msdos

Numer  Początek  Koniec  Rozmiar  Typ       System plików   Flaga
 1     1049kB    318GB   318GB    primary   ext4            ładowalna
 2     318GB     320GB   2145MB   extended
 5     318GB     319GB   1074MB   logical   linux-swap(v1)
 6     319GB     320GB   1071MB   logical   ext2
```

There is no tree but it may help, since as you stated it would be a good to at least know the relationship. If you want to use GUI you can try with `GParted`:

[image]

Comment: I looked at that early, didn't got the expected results. It shows me the partitions but I have no way to differentiate logical volumes from primary... mm... more thickening...

Comment: @Braiam, I updated my answer. Unfortunately, I didn't found any command line way to do tree listing.

Comment: Seems that it will be the only solution... btw, fix that NTFS partition :P

Comment: It's just a screen from the web, as you see it's different from command line output :)